# Page numbering is not displayed when border is added

Tags: numbering, border

I created a document and I needed to add border to every page. I wrote the code for the same but when I run the code, in PDF viewer the page numbering of some pages are not displayed.

Can anyone help me with the same?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
    \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
     \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
      {%
           logical pages=1,%
       }
     \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
      {
             border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,
             border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
             resized width=.90\pgfphysicalwidth,
             center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth} 
             {.5\pgfphysicalheight}
              }%
      }

      \begin{document}

      This is a document.

      \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you added the border to your document?

Comment: The code I used for border is added.

Comment: I tried your code.  I see the page number fine.  What I don't see is a border.